# How to scroll up gvim terminal output of external command?

Tags: vim

It is possible to scroll up gvim's output of an ex command?

it's says "b/u/k: up" but whatever I've tried it doesn't works to scroll up.

By the way I have tried with the more option setted and unsetted (set more / set nomore).

[image: screenshot]

----------------- edit -----------------

I've executed :version and as the output is bigger than one screen I am able to scroll up with the mentioned keys. Also this confirmed that the "more" option is working as expected, because I need to have it activated for scrolling to work (if I do ":set nomore" then any key I press closes the output window).

So te problem is only when executing external commands, for example:

```
:!tree ~
```

The output is shown in the bottom window until the end but I'm not able to scroll up, it justs keeps displaying the message. Here it is an screenshot of my gvim :version output:

[image: version output]

Comment: `b/u/k` works for me. Can you start vim without plugins and try again? *(gvim -u NONE)*

Comment: I've tried and it the problem persists. I'm using gvim 7.4.52 on ubuntu linux 64bits. When I type anything after the command it just closes the terminal and gets back to the current buffer (more and nomore).

Comment: It works here (ubuntu, gVim 7.4 with patches 1-347). Try to increase the verbose level (`'vbs'`) to get some clue. If there is too much output you could use `:redir` to see the output on a regular buffer.

Comment: :set verbose (=0) hasn't changed anything in appeareance or I don't know exactly how to use it. I have expanded the question with more info.

Comment: anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: @portOdin I was never able to solve it..

Comment: @pragmatic_programmer K, thanks.